# offsetDateTime illegalArgumentException nhibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate, datetimeoffset

i am trying to map offsetDateTime to type SQL but i am not sure how to solve the 2 types.

inside my method i am updating the date with

```
List<Items> listItems = repository.fetchitemById(Ids);
  OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.now();
    if (listItems.size() > 0 && !isNull(listItems.get(0).getDate())) {
     date = listItems.get(0).getDate();
    }
```

the query is inside the repository a crudRepository with the date on it al already verified the order in the interface and the query they all match

when i evaluate the expression

```
listItems.get(0).getDate()
```

i get

> Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception.
>   Projection type must be an interface!
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Projection type must be an interface!

Also inside the schema the date is a TIMESTAMP with NULL DEFAULT NULL

any thoughts

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<Items> listItems = repository.fetchitemById(Ids);
      OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.now();
        if (listItems.size() > 0){
          if(!isNull(listItems.get(0).getDate())) {
         date =Timestamp.valueOf(listItems.get(0).getDate().toLocalDateTime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: same thing, it appears that the problem only persists with OffsetDateTime because it works just fine with a string or any other type, i also know that offsetDateTime maps to timeStamp in sql.

Comment: if now referes to date then it is wrong, they're 2 different types'